# how to fix laravel installation failed because extension not enable

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu

**this is my command**

```
danil@danil-Lenovo-ideapad-120S-14IAP:~/.config/composer$ composer global require laravel/installer
    Changed current directory to /home/danil/.config/composer
    Using version ^3.0 for laravel/installer
    ./composer.json has been created
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

**Problem 1**

```
    - laravel/installer v3.0.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - laravel/installer v3.0.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v3.0.0, v3.0.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json
```

that is my error message
I don't know how to activate it

Comment: you should install the php7.2-zip in your ubuntu using this command :

`sudo apt install php7.2-zip`

Comment: thank you @M.FahmiUlulAzmi it's work on me

Comment: @user9276279 Please add a Q&A style to this question. It seems your problem was resolved.